# jQuery each() method filter with is() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Every input field of a page will get different color. 
**For example:** any "input" element will be red border
any "textarea" element will be blue border
any "select" element will be green border
 Here is my jquery code to do that:

```
    $("input, textarea, select").each(function(event){
        var fields = $(event.fields);
        if( fields.is("input") ) {
            fields.css( "border-color", "red" );
        } else if ( fields.is("textarea") ) {
            fields.css( "border-color", "blue" );
        } else if ( fields.is("select") ) {
            fields.css( "border-color", "green" );
        }
    });
```

Its not working, also no error in the console

Comment: `.each()` has nothing to do with events.

Comment: why cant you use css `input{border:1px solid red;}` `textarea{border:1px solid blue;}` `select{border:1px solid green;}`

Comment: No, cause this is just a demonstration for the real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.each()` parameters are incorrect, each function provide object in 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter and 1<sup>st</sup> parameter index, try this code

```
$("input, textarea, select").each(function(index, object){
        var fields = $(object);
        if( fields.is("input") ) {
            fields.css( "border-color", "red" );
        } else if ( fields.is("textarea") ) {
            fields.css( "border-color", "blue" );
        } else if ( fields.is("select") ) {
            fields.css( "border-color", "green" );
        }
});
```

OR you can also use `this` to get current DOM ref

```
        var fields = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var fields = $(event.fields);
```

try

```
var fields = $(this);
```

Because

```
$("input, textarea, select").each(function(event){
    console.log(event.fields);
});
```

prints `undefined` - `event` has no property `fields`

Comment: `event` is return index not undefined